# Visual Basic Help, format check

Tags: vb.net

When I enter a non-numeric value into a numeric field, vb auto validates the field and the system does not allow me to proceed to fill the next text box.

How can I work around this? I want to write code to perform the validation on the numeric.

This is what happened as shown in picture. I cannot continue to input other fields.

[image]field

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an event handler that is limiting the input to numeric fields and possibly setting the focus on the textbox. This could be in Keydown, Leave, TextChanged, or some other events. You can replace this validation code with your own.

Comment: im loading the details from my database into visual basic and shown in datagridview